# QDockWidget - remove handle

Tags: c++, qt

Is there an easy way to remove the QDockWidget's resize handle?  My dock widget can't be resized (the sizepolicy is fixed), so having the handle there is just redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is as old as Qt itself, I reported this in this [report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-6941) for this in the Qt bugtracker. Please vote it up if you want it to get fixed faster.

Comment: I'll go ahead and mark this as the accepted answer, since it did send me on the path of writing my own custom layout that handled docking widgets.

Answer (score 0):

The handle is drawn as a separator by the QMainWindow instance & I believe the only way to modify it is using a style sheet.

http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmainwindow

Setting the background color to the current palette background seems to work:

```
QPalette pal = QApplication::palette(&mainWin);
QString wcolor = pal.window().color().name();
QString style= QString( "QMainWindow::separator { background: %1;}").arg(wcolor);
mainWin.setStyleSheet(style);
```

Comment: I'm not able to check right now, but won't this just make the handle the same color as the background, but not remove it?  It will still take up space, and still change the mouse cursor to the resize arrows.

Comment: That is correct: It simply makes it so the "handle" part of the separator is no longer drawn. Additional gymnastics would be required to squash the icon change. I don't see a way to completely hide the separator or force it to be of zero size. The documentation mentions a width & and height style property:
http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmainwindow

But these don't seem to be respected (I am using Qt 4.6 rc1)

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance anyone is still struggling with this, I just discovered, using Qt 5.15 on Windows, that the sizing handle can be removed by setting QSizePolicy::Fixed in the appropriate direction on the widget you put *into* the QDockWidget (not the QDockWidget itself, which has no effect); e.g.:

```
QDockWidget *cdw = new QDockWidget("Settings", this);
cdw->setFeatures(QDockWidget::DockWidgetMovable|QDockWidget::DockWidgetFloatable);
cdw->setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea|Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
controlDock = new ControlDock(cdw, this);
controlDock->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
cdw->setWidget(controlDock);
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, cdw);
```

The resulting panel can't be resized horizontally whether docked or floating, and there is no resize hot-spot.